# ALT text not showing up in email (Outlook)

Tags: html, email, outlook, alt

The issue is that if people don't "Download Images" of my email, they can't see the buttons/links or logos. They won't even know what to click on.

When I send emails the ALT/TITLE text is not showing up when viewing it in my inbox. The wierd thing is, that some are showing and some aren't. I've checked attaching style to the A and IMG tags, I've tried different imgs (.png/.jpg) and made sure there are heights & widths as well.

Some imgs are links, some aren't but the alt text not showing is not isolated to either.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem and after some testing I believe the issue is that Outlook won't display alt text that is wider than the image that it replaces. So your alt text should be short enough to fit on one line and will work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your email client supports the applied style.

You can use this link: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

Set width and height of the image in the image tag. example is below.

```html
 <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" 
             width="200" height="300"
             alt="The Labrador Retriever, or just Labrador, is a medium-large breed of retriever-gun dog. The Labrador is the most popular breed of dog in Canada, the United Kingdom, and the United States.">
```